# Use traitsui & wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, traits, traitsui

I'm trying to modify some python code which use traitsui & wxphthon, written several years ago.
I want to update these traitsui & wxpython, but there are some problems..
(Environment: windows 10, python 3.7.6 32bit, traits==5.2.0 -> to the latest one)

In the first place, this code used traitsui 6.1.3 and I want to update it to the latest version 7.2.1, because I need to install visual studio>14.0 to use 6.1.3
However, if I use traitsui 7.2.1, it shows me an error message as below:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'traitsui.wx.basic_editor_factory'

I found any clue and came here to ask about this error. Probably this basic_editor_factory is deprecated, but there is no info about it..
Please let me know if you have any idea or further information.

Thank you in advance.

-JESuh

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a correct answer but anyway I solved this problem.
I just copied a part of basic editor factory to my code. (What a stupid solution)

Please let me know if somebody knows more elegant way to solve this problem. :)

Thank you in advance.

-JESuh